# excel vba to search for a match

Tags: excel, vba

i have a date in Sheet1 A1 and on Sheet2 column A is filled with dates

im looking for something that when assigned to a button and pressed it will look down Sheet2 column A and if any of the dates match Sheet1 A1 it will bring a message box saying match found and if no match is found it will bring up a message box saying no match found

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. But don't forget to change the name of the second worksheet if it is required.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim rangeSheet As Worksheet
    Set rangeSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim checker As Boolean
        checker = False

    Dim lastRow As Variant
        lastRow = rangeSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In rangeSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
            checker = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    If checker = True Then
        MsgBox ("Found")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you i have checked this but it says not found even though i know there is a match

Comment: I used ActiveCell method here. You probably need to select required cell before clicking the button. Can you try it and tell me the result?

Comment: ah ok this worked, thank you very much for your help, i can put in a line int eh vba to select the cell before running the rest of the code, again thank you

Comment: Glad to hear. Please mark as answered if your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim TheDate As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Last As Integer

    'Put your own name for your Worksheets
    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Feuil2")

    'I put the value that you are looking for in the first Worksheets in cells B1
    TheDate = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value

    Last = Sheet2.Range("a65000").End(xlUp).Row

    'All your date are only in the columns A
    Set c = Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & Last).Find(TheDate, LookIn:=xlValues)


    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Found ! : " & c.Address)
        Set c = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "No match for : " & TheDate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hello, thank you so much for your help but it hasn't worked it says no no match even though i know there should be a match, i have uploaded the sheet here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCNX248-7esJ4CjxlotiHLN07LaYKS-x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok I send you a request to download your file on you drive.